# find generates output only when run as regular user, not root

Tags: linux, find

I'm having some issues with a command that only seems to work when run as a regular user:

```
find /mnt/data* -mmin +119 -name '*.adsr' -type f -delete 2>&1 | tee -a /log/rsynclog.txt
```

If I use the command as a regular user, I get permission errors in the log. Once I'm `root` the command doesn't append to my log. This is one of the commands that are running in my `cron.hourly`.

Does this mean it will log only if I get errors? Is there something I can change so a successful delete shows up in my log as well?

Comment: Are yiu sure thaty it is to to being executes as root?  Because a known issue is commands failing when being executes by cron (as any user) because the paths and the rest of the environment is often different. You can test that by simply running it as root (uid 0). Regardless of that, did you mean any folder under mnt whose name starts with data?

Comment: What filesystems are mounted under /mnt/data?

Comment: I tested running the command in the terminal as root, it doesnt run. It does run however as reg user in terminal ( Filesystem of data is ext4 )

Comment: Interesting. Then it probably is not a run as root (command 1), followed by | tee now runs as regular user. Which was my other idea.

Comment: i meant everything under data, the command has worked before but i recently added the | tee command because i need to log everything in my auto-backup cron

Comment: What do I add on this command to view if it is running? And also is there anything wrong with my log command?

Comment: tee -a doesn't do anything unless I run it as regular user, then it gives me a ton of permission denied errors in my log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `tee -a` doesn't do anything unless I run it as regular user, then it gives me a ton of permission denied errors in my log

Your command seems fine. It just doesn't generate output because `-delete` suppresses the default `-print` output of `find`; and when running as `root`, it doesn't hit any `permission denied`.

If you want to log files being deleted, use `-print` explicitly:

```
find … -delete -print 2>&1 | tee -a …
```

Note `-delete -print` is slightly different than `-print -delete`. The former will print only if removal succeeded; the latter will print regardless. In a case of unsuccessful `-delete` you get a message to `strerr` which you log as well, so `-delete -print` should be just fine for you.